# How to shutdown a service correctly

Tags: c#, service

I have a service which reads from a queue all the time and I want the service to be able to handle the latest item it have received before the application shutsdown. I did some research about 1-2month ago and found a way to do it but it did not work. What I mean with not working is that when the service is stoped it takes 99% of the cpu and never quits. So I tried to make a lock around the import function and a lock at the close function, which sets import to false and then continue. The same thing happend here so I added a variable for when it is in the import function and then did a loop while the variable is true. And needless to say it did not work.

```
public void StopImportSms()
    {
        EventLogger.Write("Waiting for lock to false", EventLogEntryType.Information);
        _import = false;
        while (_lock)
        {

        }
        EventLogger.Write("Import is disabled", EventLogEntryType.Information);

    }
```

.

```
private void ImportSms()
{
while (_import)
    {
        _lock = true;
        var messages = ReadMessages(consumer);

        if (!messages.Any())
        {
            _lock = false;
            continue;
        }
        //Db insert messages
        //Send ack to queue
        _lock = false;
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
```

.

```
    public void StartImportSms()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(ImportSms);
    }
```

Comment: Are the two things running in separate threads? If not, then I can't see how it will work. Also, I think you need to use built in .NET thread synchronisation like ManualResetEvent rather than rolling your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem best addressed using events, rather than flags, as events can be waited on without using CPU time (as your current `while` loops do).

I assume that the second code snippet is running in a separate thread, you don't show it, so I'll represent that thread by `_importThread` (this `Thread` object will need to be accessible from the `StopImportSms()` method). You'll also need to declare a `ManualResetEvent` field:

```
ManualResetEvent _stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Then your import loop becomes:

```
while (!_stopEvent.WaitOne(0))
{
    var messages = ReadMessages(consumer);

    // ... further processing here?
}
```

And `StopImportSms()` changes to:

```
public void StopImportSms()
{
    EventLogger.Write("Waiting for import to stop...", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    // Instruct the import thread to stop
    _stopEvent.Set();
    // Wait for the thread to complete
    _importThread.Join();
    EventLogger.Write("Import is disabled", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

**Edit:**

Since you're using tasks for your import method, you might want to try the following instead:

Declare a `CancellationTokenSource` field in the class:

```
CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

When creating your import task use the following (you will need to add a `CancellationToken` parameter to the method that implements the message import loop):

```
var token = _tokenSource.Token;
_importTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ImportMethod(/* other parameters? */ token), token);
```

Then the method implementing the import task changes to:

```
private void ImportMethod(/* other parameters? */ CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var messages = ReadMessages(consumer);

        // ... further processing here?
    }
}
```

And finally, your `StopImportSms()` method becomes:

```
public void StopImportSms()
{
    EventLogger.Write("Waiting for import to stop...", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    // Instruct the import task to stop
    _tokenSource.Cancel();
    // Wait for the import task to complete
    _importTask.Wait(/* optionally, add a timeout in milliseconds here */);
    EventLogger.Write("Import is disabled", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

It may be worth noting that since this doesn't use the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method, the task will indicate that it's run to completion (i.e. after the `_importTask.Wait()` returns, `_importTask.Status` will be `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`, rather than `TaskStatus.Canceled`).

Comment: I think this is the right solution. The only thing I would add is I would use Thread.Join(timeout) so that it doesn't sit waiting forever if the loop is stuck. If the Thread.Join() fails, then call a Thread.Abort. Also I think you should be careful by using the term Events - they aren't really events, they are signals (or notifications). I know it is called a ManualResetEvent, but that is poor naming from MS!

Comment: Added more code in my post. I am using Task.Factory.StartNew() for creating the new thread. So I have a problem understanding how I can do the Join() call. Could I instead in the StartImportSms function save the task and use task.Wait(2000)?

Comment: @user1842278 Tasks have a `Wait()` method (you can also provide a timeout), this can be used instead of `Join()`. However, since you're using tasks, you might want to consider using a cancellation token instead of the `ManualResetEvent` to achieve the same effect. I've edited my answer to include this approach.